# Access entry content in _layout.html

Tags: templating, entries

I have some content I wish to output in the main parent _layout.html template. Seems like something simple to achieve but can't seem to figure it out. If I call {{ entry.bannerLabel }} etc it throws twig runtime errors.

I'm wondering if it's because it's outside of the {% block content %} section of the template?

Answer (score 2):

My bad. Total n00b error. Made the content a global so it can exist outside of specific template and solved it

Answer (score 1):

There might not be an entry associated with the current URL, what is the exact twig runtime error?

Comment: The error is `Calling unknown method: craft\elements\Entry::bannerLabel()`

Comment: This means that there is no "bannerLabel" field on the entry object, but the entry object does exist. If the entry did not exist, it would say that :)